# How to hide console in gtk applications

Tags: windows, gtk, vala

For example I've got simple gtk app alike:

```vala
public class Application : Gtk.Window {
    public Application () {
        this.title = "Zaebis";
        this.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
        this.set_default_size (170, 70);
        Gtk.Button button = new Gtk.Button.with_label ("Make everything zaebis");
        this.add (button);
        button.clicked.connect (() => {
            button.label = "Everything is zaebis now";
            });
        }
    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args); (new Application ()).show_all ();
        Gtk.main (); return 0;
        }
    }
```

I compile it `valac --pkg gtk+-2.0 main.vala` but when I run it I also see empty console.
How to not show / hide this console and show only my window?

Comment: Here is how to do it when using meson: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008692/how-do-you-suppress-the-console-window-on-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running this in Windows?

From https://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/ValaOnWindows :

> In order to suppress the additional console window for GTK+ applications you have to take the following steps:
>
> - Download MinGW API for MS-Windows
> - Extract w32api-x.xx-mingw32-dev.tar.gz into the Vala/MinGW installation directory
> - Pass -X -mwindows to the Vala compiler:
>
>   ```
>   valac -X -mwindows --pkg gtk+-2.0 hellogtk.vala
>   ```