# How do you suppress the console window on Windows?

Tags: windows, console-application, vala, meson-build

Take the [basic example Gtk+ app](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GTKSample) and calll it `main.vala`:

```
using Gtk;

int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    var window = new Window ();
    window.title = "First GTK+ Program";
    window.border_width = 10;
    window.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_default_size (350, 70);
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

    var button = new Button.with_label ("Click me!");
    button.clicked.connect (() => {
        button.label = "Thank you";
    });

    window.add (button);
    window.show_all ();

    Gtk.main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Add a simple `meson.build` file:

```
project('gui-test', 'vala', 'c')

dependencies = [
    dependency('glib-2.0'),
    dependency('gobject-2.0'),
    dependency('gtk+-3.0')
]

sources = files('main.vala')

executable('gui-test', sources, dependencies: dependencies)
```

With the [toolchain from msys2](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ValaOnWindows) this can be compiled to a Windows application with the usual steps:

```
meson build
ninja -C build
```

The resulting executable will have the Windows console subsystem (`-mconsole`).

It opens a console window when launched from Windows explorer.

[image: Screenshot of the running application]

How do I avoid having a console window in this gui app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `gui_app: true` in the executable:

```
project('gui-test', 'vala', 'c')

dependencies = [
    dependency('glib-2.0'),
    dependency('gobject-2.0'),
    dependency('gtk+-3.0')
]

sources = files('main.vala')

executable('gui-test', sources, dependencies: dependencies, gui_app: true)
```

This is documentend [in the meson manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#executable):

> gui_app when set to true flags this target as a GUI application on
>   platforms where this makes a difference (e.g. Windows)

[image: Screenshot of the app]